# Como comparar coordenadas (lat,lng) de un json que se encuentren en un radio de 5km de x cordenada, con js

Tags: javascript, json, array

les comento, tengo una variable con una coordenada que contiene Latitud y Longitud, con esta coordenada, debo consultar que vehículos se encuentran en un radio de 5km, vehículos que tengo guardados en un array de json con sus coordenadas. y deberia devolver solamentes lo que cumplan con el radio de 5km.

Ejemplo:

```
    var cordenada= "-33.595361,-70.706334";

    var vehiculosCord= [

  {
    "position": {
      "altitude": 743.0,
      "longitude": -70.709145,   
      "latitude": -33.595995
    },
    "id": 5
  },
  {
    "position": {
      "altitude": 609.0,
      "longitude": -70.709295,   
      "latitude": -33.593636
    },
    "id": 107
  }
//El json que recibo es muchisimo mas largo, solo que aca deje solamente un ejemplo.
                      ];
```

La verdad desconozco cual seria la forma correcta de realizar este proceso, cualquier ayuda, de verdad se lo agradecería de ante mano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero es calcular la distancia entre cada uno de ellos, para eso he encontrado una función que te lo calcula

> No voy a entrar mucho en detalle de esta función, simplemente como un ejemplo y tambien te puede servir.

```js
//https://www.geodatasource.com/developers/javascript
function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {
 if ((lat1 == lat2) && (lon1 == lon2)) {
  return 0;
 }
 else {
  var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180;
  var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180;
  var theta = lon1-lon2;
  var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180;
  var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
  if (dist > 1) {
   dist = 1;
  }
  dist = Math.acos(dist);
  dist = dist * 180/Math.PI;
  dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  if (unit=="K") { dist = dist * 1.609344 }
  if (unit=="N") { dist = dist * 0.8684 }
  return dist;
 }
}
```

Entonces para calcular la distancia usamos el metodo `filter` y nos quedamos con los que son menor a 5 KM.

```
//Para ir más rapido no utilizo estas variables.
var cordenada= "-13.595361,-90.706334";

//Declaro la longitud y latitud.
var long = -70.706334;
var lat = -33.595361;

var vehiculosCord= [

  {
    "position": {
      "altitude": 743.0,
      "longitude": -70.709145,   
      "latitude": -33.595995
    },
    "id": 5
  },
  {
    "position": {
      "altitude": 609.0,
      "longitude": -70.709295,   
      "latitude": -33.593636
    },
    "id": 107
  }
];
//Filtramos el json segun la distancia en KM.
cerca = vehiculosCord.filter(vehiculo => distance(vehiculo.position.latitude,vehiculo.position.longitude,lat,long, 'K') < 5)

console.log(cerca)
```

Y todo junto nos da el siguiente resultado:

```js
function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {
 if ((lat1 == lat2) && (lon1 == lon2)) {
  return 0;
 }
 else {
  var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180;
  var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180;
  var theta = lon1-lon2;
  var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180;
  var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
  if (dist > 1) {
   dist = 1;
  }
  dist = Math.acos(dist);
  dist = dist * 180/Math.PI;
  dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  if (unit=="K") { dist = dist * 1.609344 }
  if (unit=="N") { dist = dist * 0.8684 }
  return dist;
 }
}

//Para ir más rapido no utilizo estas variables.
var cordenada= "-13.595361,-90.706334";

//Declaro la longitud y latitud.
var long = -70.706334;
var lat = -33.595361;

var vehiculosCord= [

  {
    "position": {
      "altitude": 743.0,
      "longitude": -70.709145,   
      "latitude": -33.595995
    },
    "id": 5
  },
  {
    "position": {
      "altitude": 609.0,
      "longitude": -70.709295,   
      "latitude": -33.593636
    },
    "id": 107
  }
];
//Filtramos el json segun la distancia en KM.
cerca = vehiculosCord.filter(vehiculo => distance(vehiculo.position.latitude,vehiculo.position.longitude,lat,long, 'K') < 5)
console.log(cerca)
```

> No pongo la prueba completa, ya que entonces sera muy larga la respuesta. Para probar simplemente cambia la latitud o longitud de algun item y veras el resultado.

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

[Funcion para calcular la distancia](https://www.geodatasource.com/developers/javascript)